# Munpack and utf-8 filenames in attachements

Tags: bash, imagemagick, fetchmail

i have another UTF-8 problem. I use `munpack -C $extrdir $file` to automatically extract JPG files from emails that i received with `fetchmail`. Afterwards I use `bash` and `imagemagick` to process images that i can get with `find -iname "*.jpg*" -o -iname "*.jpeg*" -o -iname "*.JPEG*" -o -iname "*.JPG*"`. This works fine for most images, as long as no spaces or special characters are added to the filename.

In the email sourcecode the filename is written as

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?V2FuZGVydW5nIFNwaWVsd2VnIDIuSlBH?="
```

. `munpack` save the file as

```
=XUTF-8XBXV2FuZGVydW5nIFNwaWVsd2VnIDIuSlBHX=
```

I could add `"*XUTF*"` to `find`, but then other types of attachements like txt-files might be processed by `imagemagick` as well. `munpack` also replaces "?" with "X" that is why I can not decode the filenames.

Do you have a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround has done it for me. Unfortunately, the filenames are lost. But that was not what i was after.

Use `munpack` and pipe the output in a file:

```
munpack -C $extrdir $file > attachments
```

The content of the `attachements` file you will now see what was extracted:

```
=XUTF-8XBXV2FuZGVydW5nTGFpdHNjaGVuYmFjaDExLkpQRw==X= (image/jpeg)
=XUTF-8XBXV2FuZGVydW5nTGFpdHNjaGVuYmFjaDE3LkpQRw==X= (image/jpeg)
...
```

Now loop through each of the lines, check if it is a images and rename them:

```
while read p; do
    if [[ $p == *"image"* ]]
    then
        FLNM=attach_${num}.jpg
        IFS=' (' read -a array <<< "$p"
        mv "${array[0]}" "$FLNM"
    fi
    num=$((num + 1))
done <attachements
```

The output in the directory will then be:

```
attach_1.jpg
attach_2.jpg
attach_3.jpg
```